# React Native - Promise returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a js file that returns whether I have internet connection or not, and then in another js I have an if else statement that gets that value. The thing is im getting connection = undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

const isConnected = function() {
  NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("state.isConnected: ", state.isConnected)
    return state.isConnected
  });
}

export default isConnected;
```

```
import isConnected from '../../src/utils/internetConnection';

async checking(){
   var connection = await isConnected()
   console.log("connection : ", connection)
   if (connection){
      return true
   }

   Alert.alert("There is no Internet connection")
   return 
}
```

Comment: did you try returning NetInfo.fetch() from the isConnected function?

Comment: what do you get in console of isConnected() ?

Answer (score 1):

Your isConnected function is not a promise. If you wish to use async/await, isConnected must be a promise.

Try this:

```
const isConnected = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
      console.log("state.isConnected: ", state.isConnected)
      resolve(state.isConnected);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: (0, _internetConnection.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _internetConnection.default)()', '(0, _internetConnection.default)' is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
export const isConnected = async function () {
    var networkState = await NetInfo.fetch()
    return networkState.isConnected
}
```

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: (0, _internetConnection.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _internetConnection.default)()', '(0, _internetConnection.default)' is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this, but it could be as simple as

```js
const isConnected = function() {
  return NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
    console.log("state.isConnected: ", state.isConnected)
    return state.isConnected
  });
}
```

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: (0, _internetConnection.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _internetConnection.default)()', '(0, _internetConnection.default)' is undefined)

Comment: you should use a try/catch block in checking and see what the issue is. either that or add a .catch() block to your isConnected Promise

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't return anything in isConnected function. let's try this 
code:

```js
const isConnected = async function() {
  const { isConnected } = await NetInfo.fetch()

  return isConnected;
}
```

```js
async checking(){
  var connection = await isConnected()

  return Boolean(connection)
}
```

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: (0, _internetConnection.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _internetConnection.default)()', '(0, _internetConnection.default)' is undefined)

Comment: Make sure the isConnected function imported correctly.